# How we can pass parameter in form of query string and access response in JSON in Servicestack

Tags: service, servicestack

Below is service URL which return output in form of JSON.

```
http://localhost:8000/ByDept/ExmapleService?format=json
```

But I want to pass `querystring` parameter with this URL. Below is Service URL.

```
 http://localhost:8000/ByDept/ExmapleService?abc=hello&format=json
```

here `abc=hello` is parameter which is pass through query string.
But using this url i am able to receive output in form of JSON.

So how we can pass parameter in form of query string and access response in json.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Content Negotiation section in the Routing docs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Routing#content-negotiation) shows different ways you can specify the response format, e.g:

- [/rockstars?format=json](http://razor.servicestack.net/rockstars?format=json)
- [/rockstars.json](http://razor.servicestack.net/rockstars.json)

In addition you can also specify a JSON response with the Accept Request Header, e.g:

```
Accept: application/json
```

Both of the above accept extra query params without changing the Response Type:

- [/rockstars?id=1&format=json](http://razor.servicestack.net/rockstars?id=1&format=json)
- [/rockstars.json?id=1](http://razor.servicestack.net/rockstars.json?id=1)

So I don't really understand what the question is.